# Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. VPS connection

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, linode

When I write to console:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-first
```

to create a kafka consumer in VPS it gives me error like this:

> "[2021-03-08 18:54:24,548] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-19666] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)"

How to solve this error ?

*I checked all of the questions with same error.
**kafka and zookeeper are running.
***212.71.238.187 is my VPS ip

server.properties:

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://212.71.238.187:9092
zookeeper.connect=212.71.238.187:2181
```

Comment: Why are you not using the VPS IP in your command? If you're running it on the same machine, then it seems Kafka is not running and you need to look at the server logs

Comment: If on same machine, try setting the internal ip instead of localhost

Comment: I restart the kafka and zookeeper. Problem is solved itself. Thank you guys.